# Distinctly vs Distinctively

Tags: word-choice, differences

I use the latter most of the time, but I am unsure where the former is more appropriate. What are the different uses of "distinctly" vs "distinctively"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The difference in meaning is as follows:

["Distinctly"](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/distinctly) means:

> 1. in a distinct manner; clearly:
>    *Speak more distinctly.*
> 2. without doubt; unmistakably.

["Distinctively"](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/distinctively) means:

> In a **distinctive** manner; in a way that is notable for its difference.

What does ["distinctive"](https://web.archive.org/web/20170510214229/https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/distinctive) mean? It means:

> 1. that serves to distinguish between things
> 2. that is characteristic or typical of something

Thus, "distinctively" is used when someone said something "in a special way" for a special effect, such as distinguishment, while "distinctly" is clearly, or unmistakably.

Someone who said:

> He spoke distinctly/means he spoke clearly
> He spoke distinctively/He spoke in a manner that was notable for its difference/in a manner so that he can distinguish something he is saying.

Comment: Few links to garnish your answer: http://en.wikiquote.org/w/index.php?title=Special%3ASearch&search=distinctly&button= , http://en.wikiquote.org/w/index.php?title=Special%3ASearch&search=distinctively&button= , http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=distinctly%2C+distinctively&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3